# Socksjs infinite loop with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, flask, sockjs

I'm using vue.js with a flask server.
The 8080 vue.js dev env forwards axios queries to port 80  , cause my python flask server is always running on port 80, waiting for web services calls.

This is my vue.js vue.config.js file :

```
module.exports = {
    outputDir: "dist",
    // relative to outputDir
    assetsDir: "static"   ,
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'http://localhost:80'
      }
};
```

everything works except that Im getting sock-js infinite loops, especially when developping on port 8080 :

[image]

How can I stop theses queries, please .

I there any way to only forwards AXIOS queries to port80, not the others things ?

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1021

EDIT : Tried this with no luck

**vue.config.js :**

```
module.exports = {
  outputDir: "dist",

  // relative to outputDir
  assetsDir: "static",
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "^/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:80"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

error :

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :** Hey Guys, finally resolved with this code , simply write this in your vue.config.js at the root of the vue.js app, so the wrong **sockjs-node** queries will get ignored, only web services will be forwarded :

```
module.exports = {
  outputDir: "dist",
  assetsDir: "static",
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:80"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Then, do an axios query from vue.js like this :

```
const path = '/api/read_linear_solution';
            axios.post(path, this.form)
```

Then, in ur python or node server , the web service must look like this

`@app.route('/api/read_linear_solution', methods=['POST'])`